# Additional bookmarks with moderncv

Tags: moderncv, bookmarks

I finished my cv with moderncv and have some trouble getting rid of the errors, hope someone can help me out. I use moderncv 1.4 and tried to add additional bookmarks to the document for the attachments like in this MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, sans]{moderncv}

\firstname{My}
\familyname{Name}
\address{MyAddress}{MyCity}
\phone{MyPhone}
\mobile{MyMobile}
\email{MyMail}

\moderncvtheme[blue,sans]{casual}

\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\begin{document}

\bookmark[page=\thepage,level=0]{First attachment}
attachment 1

\bookmark[page=\thepage,level=0]{Second attachment}
attachment 2

\end{document}
```

Problem is I get an option clash for package hyperref: "The package hyperref has already been loaded with options: [] There has now been an attempt to load it with options [unicode]". How should I fix this? Another thing that bothers me is that the first bookmark is greyed out, I don´t know what that means in Acrobat Reader, but it can´t be right, can it?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that moderncv loads `hyperref` forced at the end of the preamble. In other words, it is always loaded after everything else. In the moderncv package, `hyperref` is loaded with the option `unicode` for CJK compatibility. This classes with `bookmark`, because it loads hyperref without the unicode option, and options are only allowed the first time a package is loaded.

You can solve this by enforcing the option unicode is passed to `hyperref` when loading the package, before the documentclass, etc. is even loaded.
For this you need `\PassOptionsToPackage{unicode}{hyperref}`. The full code becomes as follows, which loads without problems:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{unicode}{hyperref}
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, sans]{moderncv}

\firstname{My}
\familyname{Name}
\address{MyAddress}{MyCity}
\phone{MyPhone}
\mobile{MyMobile}
\email{MyMail}

\moderncvtheme[blue,sans]{casual}

\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\begin{document}

\bookmark[page=\thepage,level=0]{First attachment}
attachment 1

\bookmark[page=\thepage,level=0]{Second attachment}
attachment 2

\end{document}
```

The greyed out problem is probably just your pdf viewer, in which one bookmark is selected and the other is not. Its not because the tex code (no problems here with Adobe or Sumatra).

Comment: Thank you very much your help is much appreciated. I tested the document with Adobe Reader on Win8 and MacOSX, the greyed out problem occurs on both systems. Sometimes when I click a bookmark the grey mark jumps to the clicked bookmark, sometimes it doesn´t, very weird.

Comment: @chris; what happens when you have more than 2 bookmarks. Is still only the first one greyed out? Or are all non-selected bookmarks greyed out? or maybe the opposite? It is a weird problem, but I have a feeling it might be intentionally behaving like it is.

Comment: I have 15 bookmarks on different levels (depth = 2), when I click through them in 2 out of 5 cases the bookmark isn´t greyed out. When I click on another bookmark and click the same again it is greyed out, so in general it seems to work on every bookmark, but it doesn´t sometimes.

Comment: I think I figured it out. This grey mark just jumps to another bookmark when the clicked bookmark is on another page. Otherwise it stays with the bookmark that was first selected on the current page. Strange behaviour but maybe it´s a feature and not a bug.

Comment: Sounds like it could be both, but definetly not a result if incorrect tex code. Perhaps it will disappear with future updates.